# Как в JS запретить ввод символов «e», «-» в input и сделать ограничение на максимальное вводимое число?

Tags: javascript, input

Как в JS запретить ввод символов `e`, `-` в [этом](https://jsfiddle.net/megajs/84gL0hhc/4/) input'е и сделать ограничение на максимальное вводимое число 100?

HTML:

```
<input type="number" class="mytext">
<p id="contenInput"></p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready (function() {      
    $(".mytext").keyup(function() {    
        var numb = +$(".mytext").val();    
        $('#contenInput').text($(".mytext").val());
        $('#contenInput').text(numb + 70+ 1);
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cохранять последнее «правильное» значение. Изначально оно пустое.

При каждом изменении – по [событию "input"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) – проверять всё содержимое поля:

- больше или равно нулю и не больше 100;
- не содержит "-";
- не содержит "e";

Если проходит валидацию – сохранять новое «правильное» значение,
если нет – откатывать на сохранённое ранее.

К тому же элемент `<input type="number">` HTML5 может иметь атрибуты `min` и `max`, ограничивающие вводимые значения.

```js
var $el = $(".mytext");
var $out = $('#contenInput');
var prev = '';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $el.on("input", function() {
    var val = $el.val();
    var numb = parseInt(val,10);
    if(!!~val.indexOf('-')  ||  !!~val.indexOf('e')  ||  numb > 100) {
      $el.val( prev);
      return;
    } else {
      prev = val;
    }
    $out.text(numb + 70 + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="mytext" min="0" max="100">
<p id="contenInput"></p>
```

Вообще, input с `type="number"` [ведёт себя](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420828) не очень предсказуемо: он не возвращает нечисловые значения, которые в него попадают. Если сразу начать вводить минусы в пустом поле, они не попадают в строку `.val()`. Может, сделать его `type="text"`, отказавшись от микро-стрелочек вверх-вниз?